# WPF binding to font size of other controller

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, contextmenu

I want to create binding between UpDown control in contextmenu and custom control called "FileExplorerControl"(but it can be simulated on any control ... ). When I run the program a open context menu, UpDown is empty, when I put there any number, any effects occurs. Where is the problem ?/

```
   <view:FileExplorerControl Grid.Column="0"
                                  Padding="5" 
                                  x:Name="LeftFileExplorer"
                                  DataContext=
                "{Binding   LeftFileExplorerViewModel}">
                <view:FileExplorerControl.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock>Font Size</TextBlock>
                            <xctk:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding 
                                      ElementName=LeftFileExplorer, 
                                Path=FontSize, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                Minimum="8"
                                                Maximum="32"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </view:FileExplorerControl.ContextMenu>
       </view:FileExplorerControl>
```

Error message in debug window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=LeftFileExplorer'. BindingExpression:Path=FontSize; DataItem=null; target element is 'IntegerUpDown' (Name=''); target property is 'Value' (type 'Nullable`1')

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=LeftFileExplorer'. BindingExpression:Path=FontSize; DataItem=null; target element is 'IntegerUpDown' (Name=''); target property is 'Value' (type 'Nullable`1')

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the context menu is not in the main visual tree, so `ElementName` won't work. The context menu is a small, parentless, disembodied visual tree unto itself.

Your link to the visual tree is the `PlacementTarget` property of the `ContextMenu`. When the menu pops up, `PlacementTarget` will be the control that owns the context menu. In this case, that's `view:FileExplorerControl`. Conveniently, that's the one you want.

So use `RelativeSource` to get the `ContextMenu`, then use its `PlacementTarget` property to get the `FileExplorerControl`.

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown
    Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
    />
```